# Hadoop MapReduce Based Web Java Crawler

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, web-crawler

i want to implement a java crawler based on Hadoop Framework using MapReduce Architecture and insert content in HBase .
i try to combine this 2 tutorials :

[Basic web crawler example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-basic-web-crawler-example/)

[MapReduce tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm)

But i can't understand the concept. Where to put the logic for extracting the links from the page ? What is  the input data type of the Mapper ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Basic concept will be to put the logic for extracting the links in the mapper class. The input data for mapper will be list of urls you want to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org) - it is based on Hadoop and has everything you should need and more.

Comment: thanks, but it is a homework so i need to develop my own version